# Ruby on rails project, deployed code doesn't allow signup but sign up works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project and we're working on the functionality to allow a user to sign up for our website. When I run the app locally, I'm allowed to sign up, and the static profile page I have as a placeholder renders fine. However, when I try to sign up using the deployed version, it says: "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

[Here's the website](https://kiwi-be-friends-cosi166.herokuapp.com/)

This is the heroku logs - I'm not quite sure why Heroku doesn't recognize the method `remember_digest':

[image]

On my local environment, the logs are as follows, but the page still renders correctly:

```
Started GET "/users/custom.css" for ::1 at 2022-11-12 12:28:53 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as CSS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"custom"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `show'
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Allocations: 1018)


  
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=custom):
  
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `show'
```

Is there something obviously wrong I'm missing?

Comment: What are you doing on line 11 that is triggering the error?

Comment: It looks like you’re hitting the path `/users/:id` and `custom` is being assumed as the user_id, which is obviously not a valid id and returns this error.

Comment: is there a column name **remember_digest** in users table??